# How to refresh a whoke oage except for a single certain div using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, refresh, onload

How can i refresh a whole new page and all the elements, except for a certain div section.

Is it ever possible to be done with pure javascript only?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the elements that you are trying to refresh in iframes, then use `document.getElementById("youriframeid").contentWindow.location.reload(true);` to refresh each iframe with that id.

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing a page replaces everything.

So instead to answer your question you can use javascript to overwrite the other parts of the page to make it seem like the page has refreshed.

Or you can refresh the page and with everything new and just repeat the information with that particular div.